# Does xml file reloads automatically in c#, MVC

Tags: c#, xml, model-view-controller

- I wrote a method to save an xml file from the web service. inside
  that method first I check whether the file is exists.if exists,
  delete it and save.if not save.
- Other thing is I fire this methods using timer.(once a day automatically).
- my question is when I save xml, if it exists what is happen.(Because when I run it locally visual studio asks "your xml has changed, do you want to reload it").does it reload automatically or completely delete the existing one or do we have to write a code to reload the xml file.

this is my code.

```
//method to save xml
public void sendValue()
    {
        string wbserviceUrl = "https://someurl.ashx";
        WebClient clientOne = new WebClient();
        string result = clientOne.DownloadString(wbserviceUrl);

        XmlDocument cruisexmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"D:/Anuprojects/Mppro/XmlFiles/Cruisedata/cruiseprodutsfour.xml"))
       {
           System.IO.File.Delete(@"D:/Anuprojects/Mppro/XmlFiles/Cruisedata/cruiseprodutsfour.xml");
           cruisexmlDocument.LoadXml(result);
           cruisexmlDocument.Save("D:/Anuprojects/Mppro/XmlFiles/Cruisedata/cruiseprodutsfour.xml");
       }
        else
        {
            cruisexmlDocument.LoadXml(result);
            cruisexmlDocument.Save("D:/Anuprojects/Mppro/XmlFiles/Cruisedata/cruiseprodutsfour.xml");
        }

    }

//set daily time
  public void setupTimer(TimeSpan savingTime)
        {

            DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan timeTogo = savingTime - current.TimeOfDay;

            if(timeTogo < TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.timer = new Timer(x =>
            {
                this.sendValue();
            },null,timeTogo,InfiniteTimeSpan);

        }


//run it in the controller
 public ActionResult Show()
{

   setupTimer(new TimeSpan(11, 05,00));

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question, it is that  if file already exist will it reload on execution?Answer to that would be that it depends on editor that you are using.

Comment: does it happen when I host this site

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting this error is like "the same file name is already exists in the directory.".Suggestion would be

1. Delete the exisitng file and save it [or]
2. Save the data with the date format like Products23102015.xml